# How to insert form data in to mysql using express ejs

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, ejs

I am new to `Node.JS`, so I created a form in express ejs in `views/pages/profile.ejs` as follow:

```
<form role="form" action="/profile" method="post">
  <div class="box-body">
    <h4>Generl Details</h4>
    <div class="input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email_id">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" name="first_name">
    </div>
    <br/>
    <div class="input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
       <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" name="last_name">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="address" placeholder="Enter you Address ..."></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Gender</label>
        <select class="form-control">
          <option>Male</option>
          <option>Female</option>
        </select>
      </div>
  </div><!--/.col (left) -->
  <!-- right column -->
  <div class="box-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="profilesubmit" value="submit">
  </div>
</form>
```

I want to insert this form in the MySql database on submit.

I have create a dbquery/index.js for all DB queries. This file looks like:

```
// load up the user model
var mysql = require('mysql');
var bcrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');
var dbconfig = require('../config/database');
var connection = mysql.createConnection(dbconfig.connection);
connection.query('USE ' + dbconfig.database);
var express  = require('express');
var app      = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
/*app.use( bodyParser.json() );       // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({     // to support URL-encoded bodies
  extended: true
})); */
app.use(express.bodyParser()); // get information from html forms
module.exports = function(dbquery) {
app.post("/profile", function(req, res){
    connection.query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ?",[username], function(err, rows) {
        if (err)
            return done(err);
        if (rows.length) {
            return done(null, false, req.flash('signupMessage', 'That username is already taken.'));
        } else {
            // if there is no user with that username
            // create the user
            console.log(req.body.first_name);
            var newUserMysql = {
                email_id : req.body.email_id,
                first_name : req.body.first_name,  // use the generateHash function in our user model
                last_name : req.body.last_name
            };

            var insertQuery = "INSERT INTO users ( email_id, first_name, last_name ) values (?,?)";

            res.send(connection.query(insertQuery,[newUserMysql.email_id, newUserMysql.first_name, newUserMysql.last_name],function(err, rows) {
                        newUserMysql.id = rows.insertId;

                        return done(null, newUserMysql);
                    }));
        }
    });
});
};
```

This all I have done for inserting data in to `MySQL`. 
Nothing is added into `table`. Also let me know if any other details needed. 
Any help on this will be great.
Thank you...

Comment: which version of express are u using?

Comment: do u have any node server error?or console error?

Comment: no error is displaying.

Comment: i really need help on this?